# How to show $\,f(x)=3e^{2x} -10x -7x^2\,$ has a minimum on $\,[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have been told that $$f(x)=3e^{2x} -10x -7x^2$$
and I need to show that it has a local minimum on the interval $[0,1]$.
How would you show this?

Comment: This is a nondegenerate quadratic with a negative leading coefficient. It will have a local minimum where $f'(x)=0$ in the interval (if that occurs in the interval), and possibly at the endpoint(s) of the interval.

Comment: I think you mean $3e^{2x}$ not $3e^2x$

Comment: Since the function is continuous, it has a local minimum on any closed and bounded interval.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - not a global minimum for the function

Comment: @Yves No, obviously not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first derivative is $f'(x)=6e^{2x}-10-14x$ , which has a root in [0,1] because $f'(0)<0$ , $f'(1)>0$

The second derivative is $f''(x)=12e^{2x}-14$. The root of the second derivative is about $0.077$ and because $f''(0)<0$, we have $f''(x)>0$ for $x>0.08$. The second derivative is positive for the root of the first derivative because $f''(x)>0$ for $x>0.08$ and $f'(0.08)<0$, hence we have a local minimum.

Comment: where did you get 0.077 from?

Comment: With the ln-function. Calculate $\large \frac{ln(\frac{14}{12})}{2}$

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in the **existence** of a minimum, you could also go ahead and use 
$f(0) = 3 , f(0.5) \approx 1.4 , f(1) \approx 5.2$ . Now you could argue with the intermediate valuem theorem that there has to be a minimum on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Wouldn't that also be the Weierstrass theorem (or extreme value theorem)?

Comment: I'm not a native-speaker, but Wikipedia translated it as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: The theorem needed: a continuous function on $[0,1]$ achieves a minimum value.  I would not call that the intermediate value theorem.  But it is more elementary to apply than something involving derivatives.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, words are just words - I think everyone understands what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $$f(x)=3e^{2x}-10x-7x^2$$ the derivative is $$f'(x)=6e^{2x}-14x-10$$
and the second derivative is $$f''(x) = 12e^{2x}-14$$ 
Check for zeroes in the first and the sign of the second to show what you need.